# How can I mimick the listing caption style for my custom "Listing (cont.)" caption?

Tags: listings, captions, mdframed

I have the following LaTeX code which works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


\lstset{
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
xleftmargin=1em,
frame=single,
numbers=left,
numbersep=5pt,
}

\newcommand\mylstcaption{}

\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=true,
middleextra={
  \node[anchor=west] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
secondextra={
  \node[anchor=west] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\mylstcaption{Example listing of code}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=\mylstcaption, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Part of the result looks like:

page 1

[image: page1snippet]

page 2

[image: page2snippet]

Now I would like to have similar looking captions (same font size etc.) which is currently not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Style of the caption label

The caption style of your listing captions is not applied to the caption of your "continued" listing. That can be achieved by simply substituting

```
{\captionfont{\captionlabelfont\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):}~\mylstcaption};},
```

for

```
{\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
```

in your code (two occurences).

### Centring of the caption

The caption of your continued listing is not centred. This can be achieved by performing some arithmetic operations on node coordinates defined by `mdframed`. According to the `mdframed` source code, `O` and `P` correspond to the coordinates of the lower left-hand-side corner and upper right-hand-side corner of the `tikz` bounding box, respectively. `O|-P` therefore corresponds to the upper left corner. You want to construct the point located halfway between points `(O|-P)` and `(P)` (see the diagram below); that's where the caption should be located.

```
O|-P      point of interest        P
*-----------------*----------------*
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
*----------------------------------*
O
```

To construct that midpoint, you can use the `tikz` library called `calc`, like so:

```
($.5*(O|-P) + .5*(P)$)
```

Finally, get rid of your `anchor` specification, which isn't needed anymore.

**Note**: remember that if you change the `caption` settings later on (e.g. if you decide you prefer listings captions to be flush left), you will also have to change the position of your continued listing's caption accordingly. A more automated approach would check the caption justification and place the "continued" listing's caption accordingly. Maybe I'll do that... later.

---

### Screenshots of the output

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % needed for arithmetic operations on coordinates

\lstset{
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
xleftmargin=1em,
frame=single,
numbers=left,
numbersep=5pt,
}

\newcommand\mylstcaption{}

\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=true,
middleextra={
  \node at ($.5*(O|-P) + .5*(P)$)
    {\captionfont{\captionlabelfont\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):}~\mylstcaption};},
secondextra={
  \node at ($.5*(O|-P) + .5*(P)$)
    {\captionfont{\captionlabelfont\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):}~\mylstcaption};},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\mylstcaption{Example listing of code}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=\mylstcaption, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! By replacing: {{\captionlabelfont\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):}~\mylstcaption};}, by {{\captionlabelfont \captionfont \lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ (Cont.):}~\mylstcaption};} (two instances), the font _size_ of the caption becomes similar as well.

Comment: @Pietair You're welcome. You're right; you should add \captionfont. However, it's better to put it outside the inner braces, i.e. within the scope of the entire caption, not just that of its label; that way, the entire caption is affected. See my edit.